# Meaning of フリッカー and ニュル in the following sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, katakana, onomatopoeia, sports

Context: a boxer is having a hard time understanding the punches of his tall opponent.

> ノッポのリード…　フリッカーでもねェのに　この〝ニュル〟……　読めねっ…

Does フリッカー refer to フリッカージャブ? If so, could the first part of the sentence be translated as "Even though he doesn't use flicker jabs to take the lead..."?

As for ニュル, I thought it could be the katakana for "null", but I am not sure how it could fit the context. Could it have something to do with the ニュル onomatopoeia seen in the same page?

[Here you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAF0A.jpg) the whole page. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ニュル has nothing to do with "null". This ニュル (ニュルニュル, にゅるり, ニュルっと, etc) is an onomatopoeia that describes a smooth and "wet" movement of something (often long or blobby), for example, a snake coming out of a hole, toothpaste being pushed from a tube, potato being cut with a potato cutter, a tongue being stuck out of the mouth. The sentence says the tall man's punches are unpredictable and winding like squeezed toothpaste (as in [this image](https://stock.adobe.com/jp/images/squeezed-toothpaste-white-red-colors-multicolored-squeezed-toothpaste-background-in-white-red-and-white-colors-for-designers-and-illustrators-blot-bob-as-a-vector-illustration/175031219?prev_url=detail)).

I didn't know the word フリッカージャブ, but online articles say it's a whip-like unpredictable punch, so I think it can be described with ニュル, too. If I understand correctly, this リード refers to リードパンチ/リードジャブ, and フリッカー is a type of リード. (リードを許す on the previous page is "to allow someone to take a lead")

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the image you provided perfectly conveyed the meaning of the onomatopoeia! It looks like the word フリッカージャブ was already used in はじめの一歩 for [間柴了's punches](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%96%93%E6%9F%B4%E4%BA%86).